# AVG function calculates correctly in a SELECT with GROUP BY but not with an UPDATE for some records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I have a simple detail table listing a customer number and a corresponding score in float format, when I do an average using AVG with Group By customer in a Select, it correctly calculates the score averages for each customer, but if want to update a master table with the customer number with its average score using the original Select, my Update query is calculating averages incorrectly for some of the customers, so I wonder where the error might lie.

Tried to use Cast to decimal with two decimal points in the Update query on the select part of it, as data has 17 decimal points, but issue remains.
This is just a test on 16 records but I have to nail down the issue before continuing.

```
--AVG used only in Select correctly does the average calculation from the detail (child) table SELECT sd.customer, AVG(score) AS avg_score_group from score_detail as sd
        JOIN score_master as sm ON sd.customer = sm.customer
        GROUP BY sd.customer
    -- Using AVG to actually update the master table with averages from child 
    -- table has incorrect calculations for some grouped records
        UPDATE score_master
        SET avg_score = t.avg_score_group
        FROM (
        SELECT AVG(score) AS avg_score_group from score_detail as sd
        JOIN 
        score_master as sm
        ON
        sd.customer = sm.customer
        GROUP BY sd.customer
        ) AS t
    --Let us explore master table
        SELECT * FROM  score_master;
--Table structures:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[score_detail](
[customer] [float] NULL,
[score] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[score_master](
[customer] [float] NULL,
[avg_score] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
-- Data to calculate average has 17 Decimal points:
INSERT [dbo].[score_detail] ([customer], [score]) VALUES (2, -0.07216878364870323)
```

I would expect the same results in the Select-only from detail table to appear in the Update query for the master table, but some are not correct, i.e. customers 4 and 7:

```
Cust No -   Avg in Detail table     - Avg in Master table  
2           -0.0681                 -0.0681  
4            0.0000                  0.1127  
7            0.0184                 -0.0681  
16           0.1127                  0.1127
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a where clause in the sub query used in the update and this looks incorrect... there is no correlation and thus no guarantee which value is chosen from the results of the sub-query. Try rewriting your update query like so:

```
UPDATE score_master
SET avg_score = (
    SELECT AVG(score)
    FROM score_detail
    WHERE score_detail.customer = score_master.customer
)
```

Having said that, I would recommend that you do not store values that can be calculated on demand. Create a view for the averages instead.

Comment: Great explanation, I tried it and now is doing what was expected

Comment: @Renaud It would be great if you could now mark the suggestion as an answer - because that is how others find answers to similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe rows you targeted for update in UPDATE statement don't get selected properly, you have to connect updated table and table with averages using INNER JOIN (or just JOIN, which is actually INNER JOIN):

```
    UPDATE score_master
    SET avg_score = t.avg_score_group
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT AVG(score) AS avg_score_group , sd.customer AS customer
       FROM score_detail as sd
       JOIN score_master as sm
       ON
       sd.customer = sm.customer
       GROUP BY sd.customer          
    ) AS t
    JOIN score_master ON score_master.customer = t.customer
```

Here is SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50cf30/17

Comment: Now I see what I missed, I appreciate your response